# Copy assets as part of Angular 9 Library build

Tags: angular-cli

I am reading this: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries and it states:

> Starting with version 9.x of the ng-packagr tool, you can configure the tool to automatically copy assets into your library package as part of the build process. You can use this feature when your library needs to publish optional theming files, Sass mixins, or documentation (like a changelog).

And the link takes you here: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/copy-assets.md

To me, that is so ambiguous. It doesn't tell you where to put that option, but from the description it sounds like it's part of **options**:

```
"options": {
  "tsConfig": "projects/situ-angular-components/tsconfig.lib.json",
  "project": "projects/situ-angular-components/ng-package.json",

  "assets": [
    "CHANGELOG.md",
    "./styles/**/*.theme.scss"
  ]
},
```

If I do that, I get this error:

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
> Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(assets).

My full angular.json looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "situ-angular-components": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/situ-angular-components",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/situ-angular-components/src",
      "prefix": "situ",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/situ-angular-components/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/situ-angular-components/ng-package.json",

            "assets": [
              "CHANGELOG.md",
              "./styles/**/*.theme.scss"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/situ-angular-components/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/situ-angular-components/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/situ-angular-components/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/situ-angular-components/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/situ-angular-components/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/situ-angular-components/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "8db81fee-b0bd-41b0-a453-27aa6be6cc88"
  },
  "defaultProject": "situ-angular-components"
}
```

If I move the **assets** to the level below, I get no errors, but no assets get copied:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "situ-angular-components": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/situ-angular-components",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/situ-angular-components/src",
      "prefix": "situ",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/situ-angular-components/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/situ-angular-components/ng-package.json"
          },

          "assets": [
            "CHANGELOG.md",
            "./styles/**/*.theme.scss"
          ],
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/situ-angular-components/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/situ-angular-components/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/situ-angular-components/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/situ-angular-components/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/situ-angular-components/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/situ-angular-components/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "8db81fee-b0bd-41b0-a453-27aa6be6cc88"
  },
  "defaultProject": "situ-angular-components"
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out.
You just need to edit your **ng-package.json** file and add your assets:

```
"assets": [
  ".npmrc"
],
```

That will copy your files.